# How do you remove an autoscale rule that refers to a deleted resource?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

We have some autoscale rules that were set on the volume of messages sat on a ServiceBus queue. In the meantime, that queue is now a topic, so the rules refer to a resource that doesn't exist.

It's now the case that I can't seem to edit the rules at all - so I can't switch to manual scaling, nor to automatic, as the rules are invalid :(

So, how can I remove the rules?

Comment: Can you please try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/autoscale?view=azure-cli-latest) and let me know- `az monitor autoscale delete --resource-group <ResourceGroup> --name <AutoscaleSettingName>`

Comment: Couldn't get that to use the correct tenant, but....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems whatever was causing the rules blade to fail to load last week when a rule refers to a deleted resource, has been resolved, and I can now delete the rules for the deleted resource.

Comment: Splendid... not autoscale but autoresolve sure did work :-D